# New line in serialised array PHP

Tags: php

When taking data from a HTML form and storing a value in a serialised array if there is a new line the serialisation is going wrong with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

for example this outputs a string of the wrong length also plus the new line has been removed

```
$value="new\r\nline";

mysql_real_escape_string($value);


$array=array();
$array[0]=$value;

$array=serialize($array);

echo $array;
```

prints out `a:1:{i:0;s:9:"new line";}`

Comment: Wrong length? `"new\r\nline"` has 9 bytes, the length is correct. Only because you don't see the newline does not mean it's not there. Often characters like `"\r"` or `"\n"` are not visible explicitly, e.g. in your browser. But instead, specifically in your browser, converted to whitespace and normalized to a single space even if there are multiple whitespace characters. Use view-source instead.

Comment: Why do You use `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: ok for some reason it was juts when it was like this $value=mysql_real_escape_string($value);

Comment: It's just an example Michas this will be going into a database from a public form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` returns the escaped value.. you don't use the returned value, so why are you complaining about it?

also, if you check the output in the browser, you won't see the newline. check the generated source.

Answer (score 1):

If you're viewing this in a browser, the newline is just being stripped away. View the page source, or wrap it in `<pre>` tags:

```
echo "<pre>$array</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As advice, you could encode in base 64 the serialized result from HTML form before serialize to avoid errors and make it safe.

```
$encodedValue=base64_encode($value);

$array=array();
$array[0]=$encodedValue;

$array=serialize($array);

echo $array;
```

To decode youre stored value just do the reverse process

```
$array=unserialize($array);
$value=base64_decode($array[0]);
echo $value;
```

And the HMTL Form value remains intact. By the way encoding in base 64, make it safe to store the value in the BD but 33% greater.